# What makes Mactex 2023 biblatex and biber fail to produce apa citations?

Tags: latex, biblatex

Just installed Mactex 2023 on a MacBookPro 2023, Sonoma 14.4) and apa citations are not going as expected. (it runs on MacTex 2020 installed on MacBook 2011)

First step TexShop TypeSet Latex - advice rerun biber

Second step TexShop TypeSet Bibtex - no error, no warning

Third step TexShop TypeSet Latex - error Missing \endscname inserted.

The forced pdf output shows the citation followed by the some text 'labelyear' that may come from the .bbl file (biber output) line       \field{extradatescope}{labelyear}.

The bibliography

```
@article{Thomas2008,
    author = {Thomas, Christine M. and Liu, Tianbiao and Hall, Michael B. and Darensbourg, Marcetta Y.},
    date-modified = {2024-03-12 08:48:16 +0100},
    doi = {10.1021/ic800654a},
    journal = {Inorg. Chem.},
    keywords = {chemical},
    number = {15},
    pages = {7009-7024},
    title = {Series of Mixed Valent {Fe(II)Fe(I)} Complexes That Model the {H(OX)} State of [{FeFe}]Hydrogenase: Redox Properties, Density-Functional Theory Investigation, and Reactivity with Extrinsic {CO}},
    volume = {47},
    year = {2008},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1021/ic800654a}}

@book{Graham1995,
    author = {Ronald L. Graham and Donald E. Knuth and Oren Patashnik},
    date-modified = {2024-03-13 21:12:48 +0100},
    keywords = {mathematic},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    title = {Concrete Mathematics},
    year = {1995}}
```

The tex file

```
% TeXShop Typeset:

\documentclass[doc, 12pt, a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
 \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}



% the title commands 
\title{The Title of the document.}
\shorttitle{subject of this document}
\author{The author's name}
\affiliation{the institute}
\abstract{comprehensive and brief is an abstract}

\addbibresource{learnlatex.bib}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\section{Intro}
This first paragraph following the section header should be indented as well as  the other paragraphs that are following. 
This is something that we test.

This is the second paragraph that should be indented as well; something that was already observed from non-apa document classes.

\section{citing}
let refer to a resource \cite{Thomas2008}



\section{results}
apa6 and pdflatexmk


\end{document}
```

Now I have three steps and TeXShop
a) Typeset Latex results in biblatex warning to rerun biber
b) Typeset Bibtex (TeXShop engine set to biber) the results seems OK
c) Typeset Latex we have two stops and eventually erroneous citation text result

The last lines of the console output of the 1st step

```
texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Thomas2008' on page 2 undefined on input line 34.

[2] (./titlepag-1.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                titlepag-1
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb></usr/lo
cal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17.pfb>
Output written on titlepag-1.pdf (2 pages, 79794 bytes).
SyncTeX written on titlepag-1.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on titlepag-1.log.
```

Now we have the console output of the biber run

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'titlepag-1.blg'
INFO - Reading 'titlepag-1.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'learnlatex.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'learnlatex.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'titlepag-1.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to titlepag-1.bbl
```

And now the last full run with errors there are three observations marked ar the end of the line with %%%%% #

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./titlepag-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/apa6.cls
Document Class: apa6 2020/01/13 v2.34 APA formatting (6th edition)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/american.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/en/babel-american.
tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/apa6.dbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/apa6.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)

Package biblatex Warning: The starred command '\DeclareDelimAlias*' is          %%%%%% 1
(biblatex)                deprecated.
(biblatex)                Use the unstarred version '\DeclareDelimAlias'
(biblatex)                instead.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/apa6.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))
(./titlepag-1.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa6/config/APAamerican.txt)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/american-apa.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/english-apa6.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa6/english-apa6.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)))))
(./titlepag-1.bbl)
Using title for running head
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd) [1{/usr/local/texl
ive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/local/texlive/2023/
texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}]
./titlepag-1.tex:34: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.34 let refer to a resource \cite{Thomas2008}
                                              
?                                                                               %%%%%% 2
./titlepag-1.tex:34: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.34 let refer to a resource \cite{Thomas2008}
                                              
?                                                                               %%%%%% 3
[2] (./titlepag-1.aux)

Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
(biblatex)                Page breaks have changed.

 )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb></usr/lo
cal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive
/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr17.pfb>
Output written on titlepag-1.pdf (2 pages, 79296 bytes).
SyncTeX written on titlepag-1.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on titlepag-1.log.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474640/36296

Comment: The DeclareLanguageMapping should be removed from the .tex file. Then it works. That is fine as a I have a pile of apa documents to maintain.  Notice  the apa6.pdf document shortsdample.tex. It shows the DeclareLanguageMapping still there.